# Why was "should" used as an auxiliary verb in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

I know that questions and negative sentences made with "have to" use "do / did / does / have" auxiliary phrases. Why was "should" used as an auxiliary verb in this sentence?

> When Odin ruled that Agnar must die, I thought, “No, The other one will fall. I’ll see to that,” and a moment later, I turned the spear which had been heading towards Agnar’s chest towards his opponent, who fell to the ground and died with fearful groans.

> Odin was not pleased. “You can’t do that, Brynhilde, I told you to kill Agnar. That was my will.”

> “Well it wasn’t mine,” I said. **“Why should one so young have to die?”**

Shouldn't this sentence be like this? >>>> **Why does one so young have to die?**

Comment: why *does* one so young have to die? see: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35191/should-vs-have-to

Comment: Why would you doubt the grammatical competence of the writer? In any case, your suggestion is ungrammatical: it should be "Why **does** one so young have to die?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence with **should** is correct.

The sentence is another way of saying **Why is it that one so young has to die**.
It is asking for justification, whether ethical or medical or otherwise.

The alternative is:

**Why does one so young have to die?** (Note **does** not **do**)
This means much the same thing but it lacks the moral emphasis of the first sentence.

**Why should....** is always a way of looking for a reason or justification of some future deed or event.